# Connection delegate methods not called with background thread, Why ? (iPhone SDK)

Tags: iphone

Connection delegate methods not called with background thread, Why ?

In program i have created background thread and that thread set connection delegates, by setting ObjNSURLConnection.delegate = AnotherClass, and that AnotherClass contains NSURLConnection delegate methods.

But when i debug a code i have found that NSURLConnection delegate method doesn't called.
Any reason , Why they are not called ? How to solve this issue?

Comment: I have created thread using NSInvocationOperation and NSOperationQueue.

Comment: It'll be hard to diagnose a question like this. Can you be more specific or post some code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NSURLConnection` schedules notifications for events on the runloop on which it was called. You are likely neglecting to run the runloop for your background thread.

Answer (score 1):

You need to explicitly run the runloop after starting the connection. Try adding this line of code

[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:[NSDate distantFuture]];